# Different max file size for different file types?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to set different max file sizes for different file types, like:

- 10 MB max file size for images (PNG, JPEG, and GIF)
- 50 MB max file size for videos (MP4)

Right now, my validator only allows 10 MB for all file types:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,mp4',
]);
```

How can I set different max file sizes for different file types?

Comment: I would also do a client side validation (JavaScript) so user does not upload 12mb picture and then it says "you can not", better yet simply allow user upload 50mb file but then crop the picture / resize it (I know this is not what you asked for but it is a kind of solution) - more work for you less for user. Even tho I do not know many pictures apart taken as RAW and then converted to suitable format to result in size of more than 10 MB. Have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this question with the using if condition rule. I know, it is not best practice but it could solve your issue.

```
$default_max_value = 10000;
if($request->hasFile('file') && $request->get('file')->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'mp4'){
    $default_max_value = 50000;
}

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'required|max:'.$default_max_value.'|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,mp4',
]);
```

Comment: This is actually nice solution but I would use `getMimeType()`, since user aware of using [`getClientOriginalExtension()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalExtension) could lie about the extension (this is also stated on symfony api page)

Comment: Sure, using `getMimeType` is better than `getClientOriginalExtension()` on the security point view. But, I am not sure it is the best solution. Laravel always have some magics about the challanges.

Comment: Its actually symphony component that is being used. [`getClientMimeType()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientMimeType) is best of both worlds.